# Почему "злодейка-западня", но "попрыгунья стрекоза"

Tags: орфография, раздельно-дефис

"Чижа захлопнула злодейка-западня." Но: "Попрыгунья стрекоза лето красное пропела". Почему по-разному пишутся сходные выражения?

Comment: В разных случаях и контекстах следует разрешить авторское написание. Оформление своих слов - прерогатива (грамотного) пишущего человека.  
Если все жестко регламентировать, то мы скатимся к ущербному канцелярскому стилю. Все наши тексты будет править железная редакторская машина : *согласно Президентского Указа, осужденные не имеют права быть помилованными без их личного коленопреклоненного прошения Главе Государства*.  
Надо разрабатывать многовариантные справочники, нас же силком да тишком буровят к светлому административному раю, где правит ЕГЭ - Единый Государственный Эталон.

Comment: Может быть, уже начнем их разрабатывать?

Comment: Так ведь их не утвердят, потому что есть академические, они общеприняты.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Во-первых,"попрыгунья Стрекоза" - Стрекоза - имя собственное, героиня басни.Поэтому применяем правило: дефис ставится после имени собственного. У нас приложение перед именем собственным,нет дефиса.

Во-вторых, если б было имя нарицательное, то злодейка-западня воспринимается как одно целое,один образ( одинаково с сочетанием западня-злодейка), а попрыгунья стрекоза - как существительное с определением

У Розенталя: если предшествующее однословное приложение может быть приравнено по значению к определению-прилагательному, например: красавец мужчина(ср.: красивый мужчина), старик отец, гигант завод (но при перестановке слов: завод-гигант), бедняк портной, богатырь всадник, крошка сиротка, хищник волк, искусник повар.  Приложение-существительное может отличаться по значению от определения-прилагательного; так, в предложении: Татьяна по воле барыни была выдана замуж за пьяницу башмачника (Тургенев) — сочетание пьяница башмачник (постоянный признак) не то же, что пьяный башмачник (временный признак); Вот и у нас попрыгунья - постоянный признак, поэтому без дефиса перед определяемым существительным.

http://rosenthal.nx0.ru/sections/93/

Но это мы просто объяснили написание Крылова в его басне, он как бы подсказал нам прочтение, а если б я это писала, я могла бы расценить по-другому и написать  злодейка западня раздельно, потому что ассоциация - злодейская западня. Вообще я считаю приложение сложной темой, где трудно определить, где определяемое слово, а где приложение. У Лопатина вон все пишутся через дефис: старик-отец, красавица-дочка, умница-сын, герой-лётчик, мудрец-писатель, проказница-мартышка, самодурка-мачеха, трудяга-следователь, он считает,что оценочные приложения сливаются по смыслу с определяемым словом. Меня это вообще запутало, по Розенталю ясносности было больше.

Comment: Удивляюсь я Лопатину. Может, и хорошо, что я его не штудировала особо. В учебниках-то "старик отец". Какая-тот ползучая орфографическая реформа получается.

Comment: С Лопатиным я здесь категорически не согласна - его реформы вообще сводят нашу орфографию к примитивной записи слов, фактически уничтожая ее интеллектуальный потенциал. Выглядит эта тема, действительно, очень сложной, но мне кажется,что ее можно изложить понятнее и проще.Все зависит от смысла слов и от конкретной ситуации. Например, сравним:попрыгунья Стрекоза, попрыгунья Маша (1)и  Маша такая попрыгунья-стрекоза (2). Вот еще интересный пример:Всей семьёй идут гулять ночью вдоль дорожек ёж-отец, ежиха-мать и ребёнок ёжик. А у Лопатина с его дефисами все смысловые тонкости не будут обозначены.

Comment: Согласна. Поэтому я и против всякого реформаторства: до того запутали, что иногда произнесёшь или запишешь и начинаешь сомневаться: а может, уже не так? Может, это уже не норма? 33 года преподавала русский, была уверена в своей грамотности, а теперь вот уже не уверена- допекли своими реформами.

Comment: Почему, например, в документах: личностно-ориентированная парадигма образования, когда это ориентированная как? в каком отношении? - личностно. Должно быть раздельно.

Comment: Все течет, все меняется. Вместе с жизненными реалиями видоизменяется правописание. Иначе нас ждет застой, консервация и гибель языка. Я лично не могу себе представить неизменные в течение веков законы правописания. Пятьдесят лет - тоже многовато. "Будем резать, не дожидаясь перитонита"

Comment: С личностно-ориентированной педагогикой у меня была такая история. Зайдя однажды на какой-то  образовательный сайт, я увидела это "безграмотное" слово и написала им  об этом. И вот пришел ответ с извинениями, что, конечно же,  надо писать раздельно.  А потом, представьте, я свое мнение изменила. Дело в том, что у нас в последнее время появилось  много терминов  со второй частью ОРИЕНТИРОВННАЯ: социально-ориентированный маркетинг, ресурсно-ориентированная экономика (РОЭ), в тексте они могут заменяться аббревиатурами. А термины должны быть сложным словом (слитное или дефисное написание).

Comment: По поводу 50-летней орфографии. Правила 1956 года - маленькая такая книжечка, но она дает нам большие возможности, мы их просто не видим. На практике пользуемся жесткими толкованиями этих правил (а они становятся все агрессивнее, что плохо). Академики нам только намекнули, как надо писать, выдвинули, так сказать, идеи, и эти идеи вовсе не устарели.  Просто по мере развития языка надо наполнять их новым конкретным содержанием. Это гибкая система, с хорошей степенью свободы.

Comment: А я и против аббревиатур. Когда-нибудь потомки нас просмеют с нашими РОЭ. Они должны быть общеприняты, общепонятны, их должно быть как можно меньше, а РОЭ - реакция оседания эритроцитов (целых три слова, как видите, не обязательно одно слово термин).

Comment: На форуме был такой разговор: Вот не знаю, как  будет правильно написать: ресурсоориентированная экономика или ресурсо-ориентированная экономика, подскажите.
2. И то и другое выглядит некрасиво. Почему нельзя просто написать «экономика, ориентированная на ресурсы»?
3. Не получается написать "экономика, ориентированная на ресурсы", по тексту очень часто используется аббревиатура РОЭ, но иногда пишется полностью.

Answer (score 0):

"Попрыгунья" можно заменить прилагательным "веселая" или "безбашенная" поэтому нет дефиса.
Не согласен с ответом ранее, где написано что Стрекоза имя собственное, стрекоз много, как и муравьев.

Дефис НЕ СТАВИТСЯ в следующих случаях:

```
в сочетании двух нарицательных существительных приложение стоит перед определяемым словом и может быть заменено определением – качественным прилагательным:

красавец мужчина – красивый мужчина (но: мужчина-красавец); старик дворник – старый дворник (но: дворник-старик); гигант завод – гигантский завод (но: завод-гигант);
```

Comment: Бывает, что ответы удаляются, — «с ответом ранее» разбирайтесь в комментариях к нему же. И ещё, Крылова не стоит доставать "безбашенными" словечками.